# Cant calculate sum using values in variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running a first query to obtain totals and then I store these totals in two variable called @total and @ots. I want to use these variables later in another query to calculate some percentage values however as you can see in the picture I end up with zeros in the result set.

```
create table #temp (
count int,
ots int
) 

insert into #temp
select
count(i.ID) as  'total count',
sum(mc.ots) as 'Imps'

from 
Profiles P 
INNER JOIN ProfileResults PR ON P.ID = PR.ProfileID
INNER JOIN Items i ON PR.ItemID = I.ID
inner join batches b on b.ID = i.BatchID
left outer join BatchActionHistory bah on b.ID=bah.batchid
inner join ItemOrganisations ito (nolock) on i.ID= ito.ItemID
inner join Lookup_MediaChannels mc on mc.id = i.MediaChannelID

where p.ID = 41 
and b.StatusID IN (6,7)
and bah.BatchActionID = 6
and i.StatusID = 2
and i.IsRelevant = 1


declare @total int 
declare @ots int 

select @total = sum(count) from #temp
select @ots =  sum(ots) from #temp

select c.Name, 
count(i.ID) as  'total count',
sum(mc.ots) as 'Imps',
sum(case when ito.rating <50 then 1 else 0 end) as 'unfav count',
sum(case when ito.Rating =50  then 1 else 0 end) as 'neu count',
sum(case when ito.Rating >50  then 1 else 0 end) as 'fav count',

(sum(case when ito.rating < 50 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(i.ID) * 100) as 'unfav %',
(sum(case when ito.Rating =50  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(i.ID) * 100) as 'neu %',
(sum(case when ito.Rating >50  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(i.ID) * 100) as 'fav %',

CONVERT(decimal(4,2),avg(ito.Rating)) as 'Av Rating %',

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--problem encountered here 
    CONVERT(decimal(4,2),(count(i.ID)/ @total * 100)) as '% Total ',
    CONVERT(decimal(4,2),(sum(mc.ots)/ @ots * 100 )) as '% Imps'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


from 
Profiles P 
INNER JOIN ProfileResults PR ON P.ID = PR.ProfileID
INNER JOIN Items i ON PR.ItemID = I.ID
inner join batches b on b.ID = i.BatchID
left outer join BatchActionHistory bah on b.ID=bah.batchid
inner join Lookup_Countries c (nolock)on b.CountryID = c.ID
inner join ItemOrganisations ito (nolock) on i.ID= ito.ItemID
inner join Lookup_ItemStatus lis (nolock) on lis.ID = i.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchStatus lbs (nolock) on lbs.ID = b.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchTypes bt on bt.id = b.Typeid
inner join Lookup_MediaChannels mc on mc.id = i.MediaChannelID

where p.ID = 41 
and b.StatusID IN (6,7)
and bah.BatchActionID = 6
and i.StatusID = 2
and i.IsRelevant = 1

Group By c.Name
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2012? If so you can use count(i.ID) over(partition by c.Name) / count(i.ID) over () or something along those lines instead of running the same query twice.

Comment: @DavidSöderlund: you can do it since `SQL Server 2005`.

Comment: could you please provide and example

Comment: This is quite confusing please some work out and prepair good question . there are many information is missing . I found there are some syntax error also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With integers, `SQL Server` only does integer division. This will return 0:

```
DECLARE @sum INT = 99
DECLARE @total INT = 100

SELECT  CONVERT(decimal(4,2),(@sum / @total * 100))
```

You should first convert to a floating / fixed point type then divide:

```
DECLARE @sum INT = 99
DECLARE @total INT = 100

SELECT  CONVERT(decimal(4,2),(@sum * 100.00 / @total))
```

You can also use window functions:

```
SELECT  SUM(ms_otc) * 100.00 / SUM(SUM(ms_otc)) OVER () AS [% Imps],
        ...
FROM    Profiles P
        ...
GROUP BY
        c.name
```